# OAuth Unsuccessful Response

Tags: oauth

According to https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/

> Error responses are returned with an HTTP 400 status code (unless
>   specified otherwise), with error and error_description parameters. The
>   error parameter will always be one of the values listed below.
>
> - invalid_request
> - invalid_client
> - invalid_grant
> - invalid_scope
> - unauthorized_client
> - unsupported_grant_type

Can I have custom error like "invalid_captcha" or "captcha_required"?

I want, if someone sends wrong credentials for 3 times, I send "captcha_required" error and for next time must send valid captcha code.

My question is:

1. Is it allowed to define custom error codes in OAuth ?
2. Is there alternative way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way to do this would be to introduce a custom error code and use that in the `error_description`.

As an example, Azure Active Directory B2C has a password reset flow where upon the user clicking on "Forgot Passwort", B2C actually throws an error with the custom error description `AADB2C90118` to the application, which can now execute custom code. As AAD is one of the mayor oauth implementations, one could consider it a "credible source".

> A sign-up or sign-in user flow with local accounts includes a Forgot password? link on the first page of the experience. Clicking this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset user flow.
>
> Instead, the error code AADB2C90118 is returned to your application. Your application needs to handle this error code by running a specific user flow that resets the password. To see an example, take a look at a simple ASP.NET sample that demonstrates the linking of user flows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#linking-user-flows

```
            if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
            {
                // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
                notification.Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think so.
2. You could always add the custom error in `error_description`. For example, `captcha_required` would be

   `{
       "error": "invalid_request",
       "error_description": "invalid_captcha",
       "error_uri": "whatever you want here"
   }`
   and you could access `error_description` and see if it matches.

Comment: I am looking for "an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources."

Comment: sorry for that :)

Comment: The job of the error property is to give a concise description of what happened with the request that was just processed.  It’s entirely acceptable to use error_description for more details (like captcha failed), but it’s not an important enough distinction from the other existing error codes to merit a new error type.